# SDK version cannot be found when running MSBuild from custom location

Tags: .net, build, msbuild

I was able to build my project with `msbuild.exe /t:restore/t:Clean, Build "PATH_TO_MYPROJECT.csproj"` from the default msbuild location `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

But, when I install [BuildTools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) to custom location, `c:\myproj\buildtools`, I get `error MSB42 36: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.`

**What I tried:**

I found out that I need to set environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403\Sdks`. After that I got `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props(14,38): erro r MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.`

1. I don't want to install `MSBuildSDKsPath` as I don't want to set it to a certain version and always update manually.
2. How the MSBuild manages to locate the correct SDK version? Why is it different when I run from a custom location?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [BuildTools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) doesn't include `Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver` folder during the installation. I solved this by copying `Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver` from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\SdkResolvers` to `c:\myproj\buildtools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\SdkResolvers`